# Tarefas simultâneas (Melhor jeito?)

Tags: .net, vb.net

Olá, caros amigos!
Estou buscando a melhor maneira de trabalhar com tarefas simultâneas em um ambiente gráfico.

Já tentei utilizar: (Thread), (Task) e (Backgroundworker).
Só que em todos tive o mesmo problema: não ter permissão para manipular um objeto a partir de outra thread e se eu utilizar o método invoke a aplicação fica muito lenta. Além desse problema ainda tem outro: Não consigo receber o retorno de uma função utilizando essas ferramentas.

Eu preciso fazer uma aplicação muito rápida, quero que seja o mais fluido possível. 
Gostaria que vocês compartilhassem como usam as tarefas simultâneas... quero saber se existem técnicas ou até mesmo outras bibliotecas como essas...

O meu foco é executar uma determinada função "n" vezes e, essa função vai retornar uma mensagem em um componente como uma Listbox. Eu preciso que a informação seja rápida.

### Agradeço desde já!

---

Dei uma olhada em como o SyncLock funciona, de fato eu nunca tinha ouvido falar e até me interessou, mas continuo com o mesmo problema... Vou postar uma parte do meu código para que você possa analisar e me dizer qual seria melhor opção

Uma classe que dei o nome de conexão

```
Public Class Conexao

    Public ip As String
    Public porta As Integer
    Public estado As Boolean

    Public Sub conectar()
        Dim cliente As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

        Try
            cliente.Connect(ip, porta)
            estado = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            estado = False
        End Try

        Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add("Porta: " & porta & " Estado: " & estado)

    End Sub

End Class
```

E o código do botão

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim porta As Integer

        For index = 1 To 10
            porta = index

            Dim novaConexao = New Conexao
            novaConexao.ip = "127.0.0.1"
            novaConexao.porta = porta

            Dim thread(10) As Threading.Thread
            thread(index - 1) = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf novaConexao.conectar)
            thread(index - 1).IsBackground = True
            thread(index - 1).Start()
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

O erro acontece nessa linha:

```
Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add("Porta: " & porta & " Estado: " & estado)"
```

Se eu utilizasse um `msgbox` para mostrar o resultado funcionaria, mas eu preciso que seja no `Listbox`, e a `Thread` não tem permissão... alguma ideia?

Answer (score 2):

### Só que em todos tive o mesmo problema: não ter permissão para manipular um objeto a partir de outra thread e se eu utilizar o método invoke a aplicação fica muito lenta.

[Possivelmente você não conhece bem o conceito de **região crítica** inerente ao uso de Threads](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regi%C3%A3o_cr%C3%ADtica). Quando duas ou mais Threads alteram uma determinada informação, o trecho de código que altera essa informação é chamado de **região crítica**.

Em C#, para proteger uma região crítica, você tem que declarar um objeto e aplicar nele uma operação de [`lock()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/c5kehkcz.aspx):

```
protected readonly object _object = new object();
protected int meuInt = 0;

lock(_object) {
    meuInt = 1;
}
```

No VB.NET é bem similar:

```
Public meuInt As Integer = 0
Private _object As New Object 
SyncLock _object
    _object = 1
End SyncLock
```

### O meu foco é executar uma determinada função "n" vezes e, essa função vai retornar uma mensagem em um componente como uma Listbox. Eu preciso que a informação seja rápida.

[Usando os tutoriais de Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) você conseguirá este resultado. Apenas proteja suas regiões críticas adequadamente.

---

No caso do seu código, experimente isolar em região crítica o acesso ao `ListBox` da seguinte forma. Não é garantido que funcione porque você está acessando uma propriedade de outra classe de uma forma bem irregular:

```
Public Class Conexao

    Public ip As String
    Public porta As Integer
    Public estado As Boolean
    Private _object As New Object 

    Public Sub conectar()
        Dim cliente As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

        Try
            cliente.Connect(ip, porta)
            estado = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            estado = False
        End Try

        SyncLock _object
            Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add("Porta: " & porta & " Estado: " & estado)
        End SyncLock

    End Sub

End Class
```

O mais correto seria a classe de conexão receber a referência ao `Listbox` no momento da inicialização, evitando acesso a `Form1` diretamente, que no momento da execução pode nem existir. Algo assim:

```
    Public Sub conectar(ByRef listbox As ListBox)
        Dim cliente As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

        Try
            cliente.Connect(ip, porta)
            estado = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            estado = False
        End Try

        SyncLock _object
            listbox.Items.Add("Porta: " & porta & " Estado: " & estado)
        End SyncLock

    End Sub
```

Uso:

```
Dim thread(10) As Threading.Thread
thread(index - 1) = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf novaConexao.conectar(Form1.ListBox1))
thread(index - 1).IsBackground = True
thread(index - 1).Start()
```

Não testei este código.

Ainda, se não funcionar desta forma, [existe este artigo no CodeProject que explica como você pode modificar componentes de Form dentro de Threads](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/269787/Accessing-Windows-Forms-Controls-across-Threads). Pode ser o ideal para o seu caso.

Comment: Isto não resolve o problema de permissão cross-thread.

Comment: Acho q ficou claro agora o por quê de usar o SyncLock ^^
Mas e quanto ao problema das permissões, que opções eu tenho ?

Comment: Não sei exatamente que erro é que você está tendo, mas no seu lugar, eu passaria para a função "worker" a referência para a lista que se deseja atualizar em tela.

Comment: Poderia me mandar um pequeno exemplo de como passar a referência da listbox ?

Comment: @WesleySilva Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Lamento informar, mas vais ter de usar `Invoke`. Não há outra solução.

Controlos da UI só podem ser modificados a partir da thread UI.
Se outras threads tentarem modificar o seu estado, ocorre uma excepção a informar que a thread não ter permissões.

> se eu utilizar o método invoke a aplicação fica muito lenta.

Isso não é suposto acontecer. Provavelmente moveste código demais para dentro da chamada `Invoke`. Tenta executar o `Invoke` com apenas esta linha:  `Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add("Porta: " & porta & " Estado: " & estado)`. Se o código continuar lento, o problema está noutro lado qualquer do código.

---

**EDIT**

Outra solução equivalente (e que deve ser usado após .NET 4.5) é o uso de async/await.

Não conheço a sintaxe de VB.NET, mas em c# seria assim:

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    bool estado = false;
    await Task.Run(() => {

        //conectar ao client TCP
        estado = true;
    });

    Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add("Porta: " + porta + " Estado: " + estado);
}
```

`Task.Run` defere o trabalho de ligar ao cliente TCP para uma thread da threadpool, e await aguarda assincronamente que a tarefa complete - ou seja, enquanto a thread da threadpool liga ao cliente, a thread da UI fica livre para lidar com outros eventos.

O resto do código do método irá ser executado novamente na thread da UI assim que a task completar.